# Set the style of a custom button

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I created a custom button and would like to put a style on the button.  I would like to put the style on the button at the class level so that I don't have to set the Style property on every button instance.  Is there a way to do this? I have a Application Resource file that contains the styles for the button, just need to link the two up.

Button Class

```
public class CfcButton : Button
{
    public CfcButton()
    {
       //Set the Style here
    }
}
```

then when I have to put a button on the xaml page it will just be like so:

```
<controls:CfcButton Name="btnSearch" Margin="15,0,0,0"
                    Content="Search" Width="75" 
                    Command="{Binding SearchClick}" />
```

instead of setting the style on the button when it is created like so:

```
<controls:CfcButton Name="btnSearch" Margin="15,0,0,0"
                    Content="Search" Width="75"
                    Style="{DynamicResource CfcButtonStyle}"
                    Command="{Binding SearchClick}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up the style in the constructor like this:

```
this.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["CfcButtonStyle"];
```

and if your style resource doesn't have a key, but only a target type, then you can use typeof(CfcButton) as the resource key - but now I can see, that it has, so I updated the code...

Comment: @Corey Witherow - If no `x:Key` is defined than it's by default gets applied. No need to set style explicitly on constructor. Simply remove `x:Key = CfcButtonStyle` and it will work without any need to set it in constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Place the **default style (without any x:Key set on it) under App resources** and it will be automatically applied to all custom buttons in your application.

```
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
     <Style xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
            TargetType="local:CfcButton">
        ......
     </Style>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Replace YourNamespace with actual namespace name where CfcButton class is declared in.